# How to cut music file in external storage

Tags: android

I want to cut or trim audio song file in android programmatically. For example: My phone already  have avaiable music file time play 4 minutes, i want cut or trim song from from 2nd minute to 3rd minute, How to ?. Please guide in detail step by step. Thanks !

Apps on chplay have the same function
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mp3cutter.mixaudio.musiceditor
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tianxingjian.supersound

I have try this code but return RETURN_CODE_FAILED

trimMusic(position_start,position_end,"NAME_SONG");

```
private void trimMusic(long startMs, long endMs, String fileName) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MusicEditor/");
    folder.setReadable(true);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    filePrefix = fileName;

    String fileExt = ".mp3";
    System.out.println("audio"+fileExt);
    dest = new File(folder, filePrefix + fileExt);
    original_path = path;

    duration = (endMs - startMs) / 1000;
    filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.d("chandoixuanduc",filePath);

    command = new String[]{"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", original_path, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};
    execffmpegBinary(command);
}

private void execffmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(LogMessage message) {
            Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
        }
    });

    Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(LogMessage message) {
            Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
        }
    });

    Config.enableStatisticsCallback(new StatisticsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Statistics newStatistics) {

        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + Arrays.toString(command));


    long executionId = FFmpeg.executeAsync(command, new ExecuteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(long executionId, int returnCode) {
            if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                //  progressDialog.dismiss();
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.status_cut_music_sus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS");

            }
            else if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_CANCEL");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.status_cut_music_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_FAILED");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most accurate way is using FFmpeg, [https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit](http://here%27s) an Android library making is easy to implement.

Here's a command for trimming audio using FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -ss 180 -i input -t 240 -c copy output
```

- -ss : starting point for trimming
- 180 : 180 seconds = 3 minutes
- input  : The audio file you want to trim
- -t : till where you want to trim
- 240 : 240 seconds = 4 minutes
- -c copy : copy the stream
- output : where you want to save the trimmed audio

Comment: hi HB. I edited question. Please Instructions on how to cut music files

Comment: @NguyenDuc I have answered your initial question. You can open another question that is relevant to the issue you have.

Comment: I have already can cut music file by use FFmpeg and save in external storage. But i can not get music file cutted that in my app to play music file. I use this code to get all file mp3 in device but there is no cutted music file

Comment: Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

Comment: Like I said. I have already answered your question. If my answer helped you, accept it and ask a new question. What you are asking now if completely different from your original question.

Comment: Hi HB. i have asked a new question. Please instruct me with the fix. Thanks !
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69764698/i-can-not-get-cutted-music-file-in-my-app