# I can not get cutted music file in my app

Tags: ffmpeg

I have already can cut music file by use FFmpeg and save in external storage. But i can not get music file cutted that in my app to play music file.

I have use this code to cut music file

```
private void trimMusic(long position_start, long position_end, String SONG_NAME) {
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MusicEditor/");
    folder.setReadable(true);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    String filePrefix = SONG_NAME;

    String fileExt = ".mp3";
    System.out.println("audio"+fileExt);
    dest = new File(folder, filePrefix + fileExt);
    original_path = path;

    duration = (endMs - startMs) / 1000;
    filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.d("chandoixuanduc",filePath);

    command = new String[]{"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", original_path, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};
    execffmpegBinary(command);
}

private void execffmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(LogMessage message) {
            Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
        }
    });

    Config.enableLogCallback(new LogCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(LogMessage message) {
            Log.e(Config.TAG, message.getText());
        }
    });

    Config.enableStatisticsCallback(new StatisticsCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(Statistics newStatistics) {

        }
    });
    Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + Arrays.toString(command));


    long executionId = FFmpeg.executeAsync(command, new ExecuteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void apply(long executionId, int returnCode) {
            if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                //  progressDialog.dismiss();
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.status_cut_music_sus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS");

            }
            else if (returnCode == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_CANCEL");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.status_cut_music_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("chandoixuanduc","RETURN_CODE_FAILED");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And although I checked it, there is a cutted music file in my phonei but when i get all file mp3 to test I can't get the cutted music file in my app.

```
public List<AudioModel> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
        final List<AudioModel> tempAudioList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                    projection,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    AudioModel audioModel = new AudioModel();
                    String path = cursor.getString(0);
                    String album = cursor.getString(1);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(2);
                    String name = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                    Uri urisong=Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), urisong);
                    long duration=mp.getDuration();
                    audioModel.setaName(name);
                    audioModel.setaAlbum(album);
                    audioModel.setaArtist(artist);
                    audioModel.setaPath(path);
                    audioModel.setDuration(duration);
                    audioModel.setUri(urisong);
                    Log.d("kskskskkd",audioModel.duration+"  "+audioModel.uri);
                    tempAudioList.add(audioModel);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return tempAudioList;
    }
```

How to I can get cutted file music in my app ???

Comment: Is this an application that you want to release for production or will you only be using it on one device?

Comment: I want release for production

Comment: I check in my phone still have cutted music file. But when i get all file mp3 in external storage by above java code can not get that cutted music file

Comment: To be honest, there's so many things wrong with your logic, I don't even know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether it is saved in the sandbox path, because the permission problem query is unable to get the files in the sandbox path, you can traverse the sandbox directory of the software yourself